# WCF RIA Services simple question

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm new to all this stuff, so a question is dumb. If I'll use WCF RIA Services in my app, does a user well need to install something special to launch my app?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example check this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/weatherstation/) that uses RIA services and on the clients' end it will only require the Silverlight plugin.

Comment: Hm that's very interesting! Thank you. Do you know of some tutorial explaining how to use RIA services. Are you sure I will not need to deploy anything on server?

Answer (score 1):

RIA Services will be installed at the Server end.

For Silverlight clients, the user is required to install the Silverlight plugin.

A guide to deploy RIA Services is provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just the Silverlight Plugin and nothing more.